# Pass parameters to jenkins job with the help of userContent

Tags: jenkins

I am trying to create a so-called proxy page which will accept user parameters in Jenkins and then pass them to url for running pipeline with specified parameters.

I am trying to achieve it with the help of userContent Jenkins feature:

```
<font face="verdana" size="2px">
   <form action="http://user:token@jenkinshost:port/job/dev/job/dev-pipeline/buildWithParameters?n1" method="post">
       Number1:<input type="text" id="n1" name="n1"><br>
       <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
</font>
```

But nothing works.

I was even trying to set up the next policy through Jenkins console:

```
System.setProperty("hudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP", "sandbox allow-same-origin allow-scripts; default-src 'self'; script-src * 'unsafe-eval'; img-src *; style-src * 'unsafe-inline'; font-src *");
```

It also didn't work.

Am I doing something wrong by missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I read documentation not attentively.

**userContent** supports only static content but not dynamic.

Thus, PHP/JS or something similar can not be used there: https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/User+Content